# Dynamically inserting elements so they can still be deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to dynamically add textboxes so each textbox added appears as the last in the list but above the button.  I also want a button allowing the deletion of each textbox.  The code below adds the textboxes just as I want, but when clicking on "Remove Field" only that text is removed.  The textbox associated with that text remains.  This DOES work if I don't use "insertBefore" so I'm thinking that messes up what "removalLink" knows what to delete?

```
<script>
var namesCount = 0;

listNames = function (){

  var field_area = document.getElementById("fields");
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "txtName"+namesCount;
  input.name = "txtName"+namesCount;
  input.type = "text";
  li.appendChild(input);
  field_area.appendChild(li);

  //INSERT ELEMENT JUST BEFORE ADD BUTTON
  sp2 = document.getElementById("btnNames");
  parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;
  parentDiv.insertBefore(input, sp2);

  //create the removal link
  var removalLink = document.createElement("a");
  removalLink.onclick = function(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)
  }
  var removalText = document.createTextNode("Remove Field");
  removalLink.appendChild(removalText);
  li.appendChild(removalLink);
  field_area.appendChild(li);

  //INSERT ELEMENT JUST BEFORE ADD BUTTON
  var sp2 = document.getElementById("btnNames");
  var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;
  parentDiv.insertBefore(div, sp2);

  namesCount++
}

</script>

<body>
  <ul id="fields">
    <a href="#" id="btnNames" onclick="listNames()">Add More Names</a>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag jQuery? I don't see any used on this page and if you do have it linked, you could really clean up this code. If you don't use it, then I would remove it.

Comment: I added the jQuery tag hoping that might be the solution. I'm finding more and more that jQuery, Ajax, etc. are better solutions than the plain Javascript I tend to stick with.  Thanks for the working demos.  They solve my problem.  I'll work with the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tagged jQuery, I'd suggest using it to significantly simplify your code.

First, fix your HTML so all the children of the `<ul>` are `<li>` tags like this:

```
  <ul id="fields">
    <li><a href="#" id="btnNames" onclick="listNames()">Add More Names</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And, then you can replace the entire `listNames()` function with this much simpler version that doesn't have your issue.  I use the `.closest("li")` method to find the parent `<li>` tag to remove no matter how many parents above it is located which helps to prevent simple errors or dependencies on the exact HTML layout (e.g. it makes the code less fragile or prone to mistakes):

```
<script>
var nameCount = 0;

function listNames() {
    var id = "txtName" + nameCount;
    var li = $("<li>");
    $("<input/>", {type: "text", name: id, id: id}).appendTo(li);
    $("<a>Remove Field</a>").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
    }).appendTo(li);
    li.insertBefore("#fields li:last");
    nameCount++;
}
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tjb24/

---

As I show in the demo link, you can also get rid of the `onclick` handler from the HTML and just hook up to it with an event listener, otherwise referred to as [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) where you separate the HTML from the javascript.

---

If you still want it all in plain javascript, you can do this:

```
<ul id="fields">
     <li id="fieldAdd><a href="#" id="btnNames">Add More Names</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
var nameCount = 0;

document.getElementById("btnNames").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var id = "txtName" + nameCount;
    var li = document.createElement("li");

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = input.id = id;
    li.appendChild(input);

    var removeLink = document.createElement("a");
    removeLink.innerHTML = "Remove Field";
    removeLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    li.appendChild(removeLink);

    var fields = document.getElementById("fields");
    var fieldAdd = document.getElementById("fieldAdd");
    fields.insertBefore(li, fieldAdd);
    nameCount++;
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gTWqu/